# Problem with StoreTime and OrderTime handling

Tags: php, algorithm

Let say Stores Open at 15:00 but customers can only make orders after 16:00 (depending on the Stores Opening time), code does work below as expected

```
        $nowtime = $this->HourMinuteToDecimal(date('H:i'));

        $OrderTime = $this->HourMinuteToDecimal('16:00');

        $storeOpeningTime = $this->HourMinuteToDecimal($data[$key]['opentime']);


        if ($nowtime >= $OrderTime && ($OrderTime >= $storeOpeningTime)) {
            $data[$key]['open'] = 1;
        } else {
            $data[$key]['open'] = 0;
        }


public function HourMinuteToDecimal($hour_minute) {
    $t = explode(':', $hour_minute);
    return $t[0] * 60 + $t[1];
}
```

There is a problem, what if a Store-Open-Time is 18:00 but default Order-Time is 16:00, How to fix these solution? Customer can only place order after 18:00 in that case.

**General Rule**: Customer can only place order after 16:00 (Order-Time) but depending on the Store Open Time first.

Answer (score 0):

Orders are taken after OrderTime and StoreOpeningTime, so that means the relevant time is the latest one of those two.

```
if ($nowtime >= max($OrderTime, $StoreOpeningTime)) {
    $data[$key]['open'] = 1;
}
// ...
```